# Standard approach for dealing with attributes that themselves have attributes?

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm making a database and have a table structured as follows

```
         Att1    Att2    Att3   ....
User1    
User2
User3
....
```

where I would like each of the attributes (Att1, Att2, Att3,...) to have a boolean variable attached to it.  Something like the following:

```
Att1    No
Att2    No
Att3    Yes
...     ...
```

Each attribute is a numerical score from the user (listing preference), but I want to tag each attribute with whether it's actually important or not.  Is there a standard approach for handling this type of dependency?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have concrete example ow what Att1,2 and 3 would actually be called?

Comment: I don't think it's really important to my question, but for clarification some of the attributes might be "Coffee", "Tea", and "Creamer", where the scores are each user's preference (from 0 to 10) on keeping them in stock/available.  What I wanted to do was go back - after the fact - and flag the ones that we're actually willing to work on (important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it would be nice if we could have records embedded in tables.  However, standard SQL and most databases do not support this (although there are exceptions).

I would use a consistent naming convention, inventing fields like "IsImportantAtt1" and "IsImportantAtt2".  When I do this, I also have the convention that all the "Is" variables take on only the values of "Y" or "N".  If I want to see "Yes" and "No" in the output, then I use views for that conversion or do it in the application layer.

Comment: If you are using MS SQL then the `Bit` type is ideal for flags

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that `Attribute` is actually an entity call `ListingPreference` which has an `Id` key, 2 attributes, `Score` and `IsImportant` and a FK to `User` called `UserID`.

`User` currentley has only an `Id` key.

---

In short, attributes don't have attributes, it means your model is wrong.

Comment: You're right.  I suppose the standard way of dealing with this situation is by not ever getting in it in the first place.  I totally understand what you mean here, and if I was starting from scratch it would be a better way to go, but before I go back to square one, I think I will rename the fields as @Gordon suggests.

Answer (score -1):

Is attribute's score important if the attribute itself is not? If not, you can simply have a convention that a NULL score means the attribute is not important.

Otherwise, you can add another (bool) column for each attribute column:

```
         Att1    Important1    Att2    Important2    Att3    Important3   ....
User1    
User2
User3
....
```

---

BTW, are attributes fixed? I.e. do you **always** have the exact same set of attributes? If not, you may be better served by an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) (despite certain downsides EAVs traditionally have):

[image]

An unimportant attribute may simply be omitted from the USER_ATTRIBUTE table (assuming "no" is the answer to my question at the top).

Comment: I know that this will sound dogmatic but, if you will really be served by an EAV model you may as well write directly to your servers system tables.

Comment: @Jodrell Yup, this does sound dogmatic ;) There are legitimate uses for EAV, despite potential problems. The funny thing is: [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719814/533120) also describes EAV!

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic The attributes are fixed, so I don't think an EAV model would necessarily be the best way to go.  Your idea about a second column for each attribute though is a good one, even if I have to have all that repeated information.

Comment: @mstobb I agree. If attributes are fixed, then explicitly creating necessary columns is the way to go.